# I will exceed the 90 day ESTA limit while I am in Central America

Tags: usa, esta, us-visa-waiver-program

I am an Australian passport holder. I intend to travel to the United States under the VWP (ESTA approved) for the 90 day period.

After 83 days in the US, I will depart for Mexico where I will be travelling on a tour through Mexico, Guatemala and Belize. My entire trip including Central America will exceed 90 days. The 90 days will expire once I am in Mexico.

I do not intend to re-enter the US after Central America; however, I will need to transit through Los Angeles airport for my return flight back to Melbourne, Australia.

Am I going to encounter any problems? I am travelling with a US passport holder.

Comment: You will be fine.

Comment: @phoog I am concerned as although I leave USA after 86 days, i go straight to Mexico for another 9 days before entering Guatemala. Do you think this will not be an issue?

Comment: No, it won't, because your stay in the US is shorter than 90 days.

Comment: @phoog  US Government websites state that the VWP is valid for 90 day stays, which includes Mexico/Canada and other islands in the Caribbean. This is when it is unclear to me

Comment: Which US government web site says that?

Comment: @phoog this is only one of them (there are more). Traveling for business meetings or pleasure (not on federal government business or as members of the media). Transit through the United States is generally permitted, if the total time in the U.S., Canada, Mexico, and adjacent islands is less than 90 days.
Staying in the U.S. for less than 90 days (this includes time spent in Canada, Mexico, and adjacent islands).

https://au.usembassy.gov/visas/visa-waiver-program/

Comment: From the same site: "VWP travelers who have been admitted to the U.S. under the Visa Waiver Program and who make a short trip to Canada, Mexico or an adjacent island generally can be readmitted to the U.S. under the VWP for the original admission period. They do not, however, get a new 90-day admission period." Two points: (1) You're not making a short trip within the 90-day period, but a longer one that extends beyond it. (2) You're traveling outside of Mexico. Finally, why don't you call CBP and ask them? Then you can post an answer here.

Answer (score 2):

As you visit Guatemala and Belize there is absolutely no problem, this is a separate visit.

Note even if it were Mexico only you might get away with it. Yes, the rules say it is not but the border guard has wide discretion and what they do not want is a visa run.

Comment: Thanks. As I'm doing a guided tour, I think we enter Guatemala on Day 8 which means this is more than 90 days in USA/Mexico, will that be a problem?

Comment: @Caseypete The restriction is on *returning to the US* within those 90 days.  Since you're not planning to, the US does not care when you exit Mexico and enter Guatemala.

Comment: That is helpful, thank you. I thought the same thing, however keep seeing conflicting information online. I am worried that I will be denied boarding in Aus, as my return flight from LAX back to Melbourne is well over the 90 days (even though I travel into Guatemala etc.) I am also worried about transiting back through LA. I hope that it will not be an issue

Comment: @Caseypete As long as you have evidence (tickets etc) showing that you will exit the US/Mexico within 90 days, you'll be fine.

Comment: @jpatokal this is my issue. I exit Mexico after the 90 day period. I exit USA after 86 days, then join a tour and i believe it is day 7 or 8 that the tour exits Mexico and enters Guatemala

Comment: @Caseypete We're not getting through to you here. The US rule is there to prevent people from easily visa running across the border.  But if you exit Mexico to another country, the US 90 day clock is reset, full stop.

Comment: @jpatokal Understand. When i first enter USA on 28th April, i will not exit USA/Mexico until approx 31st July which is over 90 days, so i'm worried I will not clear immigration when i first arrive. Are you saying this won't matter as I exit the US at 86 days? Excuse my naivety.

Comment: @Caseypete Correct. When you first enter, you have the right to stay in the US for 90 days, and you leave on day 86 -> no problem.  Mexico doesn't care where you were -> no problem entering. And when you return for your transit via LAX, you could stay for another 90, but leave on the same day -> no problem again.

Comment: @jpatokal OK think I am starting to understand. My confusion came when I kept reading Mexico is included in the 90 days, which would put me over. But I realise now that I could stay in USA for 90 days, still travel onto Mexico - but couldn't then re-enter USA as Mexico is an 'adjacent' country. However as i go to Guatemala/Belize - it's not an issue.

Comment: @chx would you agree?